# Javascript error [object HTMLParagraphElement]

Tags: javascript

I`m begginer in Javascript and I need some help.
So, I need that, when I push the button, paragraph "leftside" appear

```
<div id="content">
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById("contentp").innerHTML = leftside;
                var x = document.getElementById("leftside")
                x.style.display = "normal";
            }


        </script>
        <button id="buttonI" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Show left side!</button>

        <p id="leftside" style="display: none">Left side</p>

        <p id="contentp"></p>
```

Comment: Do you want to move the first paragraph into the second? or do you just want to make the first one visible? please improve your description

Comment: I want to move paragraph "leftside" into paragraph "contentp" and make it visible, when we push the button

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to append the leftside to the `contentp` and set its display property to `block`. `normal` is not a [valid option](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("contentp").appendChild(document.getElementById("leftside"));
      document.getElementById("leftside").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
<button id="buttonI" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Show left side!</button>

<p id="leftside" style="display: none">Left side</p>

<p id="contentp"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x.style.display = "block";
```

set it `block` or another value of `display` except `none`